# Redirect without www to www does not work for a URL

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

I'm having problems with the redirection of only one urls.
And I do not know why it is the only URL that is not obeying the redirect command.

I want all urls to open with www.

**Platform:**

- WordPress 4.8.1
- Server: Nginx - Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
- Installation done with Easy Engine

> Note: I have already done all these
>   procedures:https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/www-non-www-redirection/

Thanks for any help!

```
https://www.example.org/ Redirecting to www (yes)
http://www.example.org/ Redirecting to www (yes)
https://example.org/ Redirecting to www (no) This is the problem url
http://example.org/ Redirecting to www (yes)
```

**BLOCK NAME SERVER**

```
server {
    server_name www.example.org example.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.org.access.log rt_cache;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.org.error.log;

    root /var/www/example.org/htdocs;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    include common/php.conf;
    include common/wpcommon.conf;
    include common/locations.conf;
    include /var/www/example.org/conf/nginx/*.conf;

}
```

**FORCE SSL**

```
server {
listen 80;
       server_name www.example.org example.org;
       return 301 https://www.example.org$request_uri;
}
```

**TEST**

```
    ~# nginx -t
    nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

**TEST REDIRECT URL**

```
~# curl -I https://example.org
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 23 Aug 2017 19:45:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=qg3bp00ofo92bsgob5flr4co26; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Link: <https://www.example.org/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <https://www.example.org/>; rel=shortlink
X-Powered-By: EasyEngine 3.7.4
```

**2º TEST REDIRECT URL**

```
~# curl -I http://example.org
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 23 Aug 2017 20:05:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.example.org/
X-Powered-By: EasyEngine 3.7.4
```

Comment: What does `https://www.chefclub.com.br/ redirect ok` mean? What is it redirecting to?

Comment: All urls that are with ok is that they are doing the redirect correctly and opening with www.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `chefclub.com.br` from your `BLOCK NAME SERVER` block and add a new server block

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name chefclub.com.br;
    include yoursslcertificate.conf;
    return 301 https://www.chefclub.com.br$request_uri;
}
```

Like you listen for port `80` to redirect all traffic to the `www` one, you also want to listen to `non-www`, port `443` and then send them to `www`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me. My redirect only works when I use two blocks on the server. That way all redirects work.

But they told me this is wrong.

Comment: Did you remove `chefclub.com.br` from other block? This is suppose to work without any doubt.

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand, I did it.
But of error.
My redirects are only working this way.
Take a look, please. https://www.screencast.com/t/VaqSWTbqggF
Thank you!

Comment: Your approach definitely has issues. Your `chefclub.com.br` is having two separate blocks for `www` and `non-www`. Also you are doing a `301` in first block and still including a lot of other things. You config is all jumbled up

Comment: The problem is that other types of redirect (looping) or else https never redirects to https //: www

You could show me a full block option without looping and make all the redirects to https: // www

Because until then the only way my redirects work is as I've shown. It may be wrong, but it works perfectly. Thank you!